# SQL Subquery returns more than one value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Because subquery returns more than one value, `@parameter` cannot be set. If I use `SELECT TOP 1 Name` it works. How can I sort it out?

```
DECLARE @parameter nvarchar(50)

SELECT @parameter = (SELECT Name FROM Choices
JOIN Position ON Position.PositionId = Choices.PositionId
WHERE Choices.CvId=1230)

SELECT * FROM Adverts WHERE Name LIKE '%' + @parameter + '%'
```

Comment: Table variable getting the job done, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not merged the 2 query into 1 ?

```
select a.*
from   Choices c
       inner join Position p on c.PositionId = p.PositionId
       inner join Adverts a  on p.Name like '%' + a.Name + '%'
where  c.CvID = 1230
```

Comment: Only retruns exact matches. I need to use LIKE

Comment: change the join to inner join Adverts a on p.Name like '%' + a.Name + '%'